# Validación de props react vite

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite

Hola comunidad necesito de sus ayuda, tengo un error que me sale en react al desestructurar una propiedad
[image: fragmento del código de react]

el error me indica lo siguiente:
is missing in props validation eslint (react/prop-types)

Nota: estoy usando eslint y prettier para dar formato a mi código y uso react con vite. el error es lo subrayado de rojo

primera vez que uso eslint, necesito ver como se podría arreglar eso

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Angel para la verificación de sesión dentro de la app se debe de usar un enrutador principal PrincipalRoute en el cual se manejen las rutas privadas y públicas des esta manera:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>

            {/* página principal */}
            <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />

            {/* rutas públicas */}
            <Route
                path="/auth/*"
                element={
                    <PublicRoute isLogged={user}>
                        <Login setUser={setUser} />
                    </PublicRoute>
                }
            />

            {/* rutas privadas */}
            <Route
                path="/app/*"
                element={
                    <PrivateRoute isLogged={user}>
                        <Dashboard user={user} setUser={setUser} />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                }
            />
        </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
```

Y posteriormente el componente  le pasamos la variable de sesión true, false y dentro todos los componentes que queremos que esten protegidos.
De esta manera recibimos isLogged y children así.

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ isLogged, children }) => {
    return isLogged ? children : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />

}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

hacemos lo mismo para las rutas públicas:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicRoute = ({ children, isLogged }) => {
    return isLogged ? <Navigate to="/app/home" /> : children
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

Y listo mi amigo ya tienes rutas privadas y públicas en tu aplicación en React v 18

Comment: lo hice de forma similar, solo que en lugar de BrowserRouter, use HashRouter,

Comment: Muy bien, si te ayudó dale manito arriba y marca la respuesta como aceptada. Siempre un gusto

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente es una regla de eslint que te esta forzando a utilizar react/prop-types para definirle un tipo a las props y que tu codigo sea mantenible a lo largo del tiempo, mi recomendación seria:
opcion 1: usar Typescript
option 2: desactivar esta regla

si se elige la opción de desactivar la regla de eslint, tendrías que especificarla en el archivo de configuración de tu linter `.eslintrc.json, .eslintrc.js .eslintrc` agregando el siguiente bloque haria que el error se vaya:

```
 {
    "plugins": [
        "react"
     ],
     "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off"
     }
}
```

Si se prefiere en lugar de desactivar la regla, implementar los prop types tendrías que instalar el paquete `react/prop-types` y en tu componente implementarlo de esta forma:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ProtectedRoutes = ({isLoggedIn}) => {
  return (
    <div>
     user is authenticated: {isLoggedIn}
    </div>
  );
};

// Define los tipos esperados para cada propiedad utilizando PropTypes
ProtectedRoutes = {
  isLoggedIn: PropTypes.boolean.isRequired,
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

en mi experiencia es recomendable ir agregando/removiendo las reglas que mas se adaptan a la forma de trabajo del proyecto o bien del equipo, espero sea de utilidad :)